# Programing uploading to Arduino due

Tags: arduino-due

I am new to Arduino and bit blur on how it works. lack of info on the net about it. please help me with these questions!

1. Does Arduino due allow you to upload a program on programming port and then run it through Native port?
2. Can I work with SerialUSB instance in Programming port?

Comment: `lack of info on the net about it` Then you can't be looking very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Arduino due allow you to upload a program on programming port and then run it through Native port?

You don't run a program *through* anything. You run it *on* the Due. Where you send text to is entirely up to you.

> Can I work with SerialUSB instance in Programming port?

I have no idea what you are asking there. Both the Programming port and Native port are capable of being used as virtual USB COM ports. They use CDC/ACM. One is directly connected to the SAM3X chip's USB peripheral, and the other is connected to the SAM3X's UART interface via another microcontroller as a USB to UART converter.